Chofetz Chayyim’s son-in-law
The book Ha-Tzaddik Rabbi Shimon (p 27) contains the following story, attributed to ‘the notes of the Chofetz Chayyim’s son-in-law’. Are these notes published or available, or is the excerpt in this book all I’m going to find? Thank you.


By the way, the principle behind this story comes from Sanhedrin 63b: "אמר רב נחמן כל ליצנותא אסירא חוץ מליצנותא דע"ז דשריא דכתיב כרע בל קרס נבו קרסו כרעו יחדו לא יכלו מלט משא וכתיב דברו לעגלות בית און יגורו שכן שומרון כי אבל עליו עמו וכמריו עליו יגילו על כבודו כי גלה ממנו אל תקרי כבודו אלא כבידו"

Correction, the name of the book which contains this story is הצדיק רבי שלמה "the Tzaddik Rav Shlomoh" about Rabbi Shlomoh Bloch (1886-1976), who was not only a pupil of The Chafetz Chaim but even merited to learn together with him bechavrusah. The above sefer is full of quotations sourced in "the notes of the son in law of the Chafetz Chaim", but he doesn't say which son-in-law. As far as I know, the Ch.Ch. had 3 son-in-laws: 1) Rav Aharon Hakohen, author of Avodas Hakorbonos, Pirchei Aharon & Chesed Le'Avraham  2) Rav Mendel Zaks 3) Rav Zvi Hersh Levinsohn
